# Obtener URL de imagen recien subida a Firebase Storage en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

estoy tratando de subir una foto de perfil de un usuario a firebase storage, la foto se sube correctamente, pero no encuentro la manera de obtener una url de la misma, para asignarla en la base de datos (y asi poder mostrar la foto desde la url). He encontrado la solucion para java (usando un onSuccesListener, que no esta en kotlin o al menos no con esta sintaxis), pero tratando de implementarla para kotlin, no he sido capaz. No quiero descargar la imagen para mostrarla, solo quiero obtener la url de acceso, para guardarla en una cadena.
Aqui dejo una muestra del codigo donde escojo la foto de la galeria:

```
btnSubirFoto.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT)
}
```

Y la parte donde la subo a firebase storage y trato de obtener la URL (repito se sube a storage correctamente, pero no consigo obtener la cadena, se que mi codigo no es el ideal, pero actualmente es lo que busco):

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val uri = data?.data
        val filePath = mStorage.child("usuarios").child(uri?.lastPathSegment!!)
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener {
            filePath.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                urlFoto = it.toString()
            }
            haSubidoFoto = true
            Toast.makeText(this, "Foto subida correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo un poquito más, he encontrado la solución en la [documentación de firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=es&authuser=0#kotlin%20ktx_4) (no lo encontré antes porque esta en la parte de subida de la foto no en la de descargas como pensaba jaja), os dejo por aquí el código corregido por si a alguno le hace falta. Muchas gracias!

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uri = data?.data
            val filePath = mStorage.child("usuarios").child(uri?.lastPathSegment!!)
            var uploadTask = filePath.putFile(uri)

            val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    task.exception?.let {
                        throw it
                    }
                }
                filePath.downloadUrl
            }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    urlFoto = task.result.toString()
                    haSubidoFoto = true
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Foto subida correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error al subir la foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```